# Is it correct and/or acceptable to say someone happened down the street?

Tags: grammar

As in, they walked/came down the street.

Comment: Could you please expand your question a bit? What is the connection between the question title, which uses the verb "happened" and the question body, which uses the verbs "walked/came"?

Comment: It is OK in the right context.  It implies a degree of chance or casualness.

Comment: If someone happened down the street, we must be in a multi-verse...[excuses to Hot Licks]. :) I just happened along here and thought that was funny.

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly, but you're close.

> **happen** (*v.*)
>   1.4. Find or come across by chance.
>
> <sup>Source: [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/happen)</sup>

*Happen* can be used to describe someone's discovery of something, so you couldn't replace a transitive verb with it. You could say something like this:

> They happened upon a street and walked down it.

Comment: It's perfectly legit to say "happened down the street".  "I was out washing my car when Fred happened down the street."

Comment: @HotLicks Please explain.

Comment: I was in my driveway, washing my car with a bucket of suds, a sponge, and a hose.  I looked up from my work and noticed that Fred was walking down the street.

Comment: That doesn't explain why it's grammatically correct to say "happened down".

Comment: "Happen" is a  verb.  Why would it be any less legit to say "happened" than "walked"?

Comment: Based on the definition of "happen" I provided, it makes no sense to say "discovered down the street". The usage you're arguing is minutely colloquial and not at all based on the official definition.

Comment: "Happened along" is perfectly idiomatic US English.

Comment: You could say almost anything is idiomatic. The point is to find the most universally correct usage which would be based on an official definition. [This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=happened+down%2C+happened+upon&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chappened%20down%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chappened%20upon%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chappened%20down%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Chappened%20upon%3B%2Cc1) shows that "happened down" isn't too relevant.